# Generar información en reporte de crystal "N Veces" C#

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

Tengo la siguiente duda tengo un reporte el cual me permite recolectar la información sobre un mes determinado previa selección de fechas, lo que necesito saber es si con ese mismo reporte puedo crear una especie de bucle que me permita generar "n" veces y por cada generación se guarde un pdf y posteriormente poder guardarlas en uno solo pdf.

```
private void btnGenerar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                String connstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Trabajo"].ToString();
                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstring))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        ConnectionInfo myConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
                        myConnectionInfo.ServerName = "SISTEMAS-PC";
                         myConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = "SISROL";
                        myConnectionInfo.UserID = "TECNOLOGIA";
                        myConnectionInfo.Password = "tecnologia";
                        myConnectionInfo.IntegratedSecurity = false;

                        String filePath = @"Z:\Sisrol-Net\Reportes\ReporteRolAdminHisMes2.rpt";

                        //Cargar el Reporte
                        rd.Load(filePath);
                        //Asignarle al Reporte el DataSet                       

                        DateTime TmpSubReport2fi = fechin.AddMonths(1);
                        DateTime TmpSubReport2ff = fechin.AddMonths(2).AddDays(-1);

                        rd.SetDataSource(RolAdm3Mes2(TmpSubReport2fi, TmpSubReport2ff, "0930159520"));                     
                        rd.SetParameterValue("@FECHAI2", TmpSubReport2fi);
                        rd.SetParameterValue("@FECHAF2", TmpSubReport2ff);
                        rd.SetParameterValue("@CEDULA2", "0930159520");

                        //Asignarle al CrystalReportViewer el ReportDocument                         
                        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rd;
                        SetDBLogonForReport(myConnectionInfo);

                        // rd.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, @"D:\factura.pdf");
                        //SetDBLogonForReport(myConnectionInfo);

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("ERROR REPORT: " + ex.Message, "ERROR!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("ERROR: " + ex.Message, "ERROR!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            } 
        }
```

Adicional tengo aquí el método guardar que es el que me guardo el pdf.

```
private void Guardar(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         rd.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, @"D:\factura.pdf");
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adicional adjunto una ejemplo de como es lo que deseo que quede ,estaría correcto lo que deseo realizar?, se podría?, de antemano agradezco su ayuda.

Saludos.

Comment: Carrobe, no está claro lo que preguntas. Deseas crear un bucle con el reporte? A qué te refieres con eso? Permitir generar "n veces" qué? Por cada generación de qué? Puedes darnos un ejemplo del resultado esperado?

Comment: Básicamente lo que deseo realizar es hacer un for que se repita 2 o 3 veces y que en esas 2 o 3 interacciones se realice lo que digite en el codigo, la cosa es saber si podría o no?, actualice la pregunta con un ejemplo